# Kubernetes apply command produces 'wrong encoding error'

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, microk8s

I'm trying to execute:

```
microk8s kubectl apply -f  deployment.yaml
```

and I am always getting:

```
error: string field contains invalid UTF-8
```

No matter which file and string as a file path parameter I'm trying to use. Even if I execute:

```
microk8s kubectl apply -f  blablabla
```

Result is the same.

---

UPD: I resolved the problem by restarting microk8s service. After restart everything is fine, but I still have no idea what it was.

Comment: what OS do you use? May be it should be `microk8s.kubectl`. Anyway there is a way to raise verbosity and find out some details e.g: `microk8s.kubectl -v=9 get no` All the best

Comment: this is not an answer, its more like a comment. Suggesting to move it to comment section.

Comment: share you yaml file that you are trying to apply, add more details to question

Comment: blablabla is just a dummy string

Comment: I repeat microk8s kubectl apply -f  <any string> resulting as error: string field contains invalid UTF-8

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 my linux version

Comment: @СергейКоновалов , the error you are telling is most likely due to your input file to `kubectl apply -f ` command. its imortant you share your input file and its content for further help.

Comment: @СергейКоновалов, please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a wrong format in the manifest, instead, it's a corrupted cache in `$HOME/.kube/`

try to delete the cache:

`rm -rf $HOME/.kube/http-cache`

`rm -rf $HOME/.kube/cache`

Answer (score 1):

I have posted Community Wiki answer for better visibility.

As OP has mentioned in the question, he resolved the problem by restarting microk8s service:

> I resolved the problem by restarting microk8s service. After restart everything is fine.